# Different position.y in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, position

I've got a navbar which sticks to the top on scroll. I have a code to get the position of the navbar after scroll. In Chrome I get **position.x = 0**, and **position.y = 0** as expected as the navbar is right at the top of the site. BUT....if I run the same code in Firefox, I get **position.x = 0** and **position.y = -775** although the navbar sticks to the top. Anyone any idea?

Code is below:

```
function getPosition(el) {
    var xPos = 0;
    var yPos = 0;

    while (el) {
      if (el.tagName == "BODY") {

        var xScroll = el.scrollLeft || document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
        var yScroll = el.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

        xPos += (el.offsetLeft - xScroll + el.clientLeft);
        yPos += (el.offsetTop - yScroll + el.clientTop);
      } else {

        xPos += (el.offsetLeft - el.scrollLeft + el.clientLeft);
        yPos += (el.offsetTop - el.scrollTop + el.clientTop);
      }

      el = el.offsetParent;
    }
    return {
      x: xPos,
      y: yPos
    };
  }

  window.addEventListener("scroll", updatePosition, false);
  window.addEventListener("resize", updatePosition, false);

  function updatePosition() {
    position = getPosition(myElement);
  } 

var myElement = document.querySelector("#site-navigation"); 
var position = getPosition(myElement);
alert("The image is located at: " + position.x + ", " + position.y);
```

Comment: Can you also provide the CSS of `#site-navigation` and/or any other relevant CSS

Answer (score 0):

The code Works just fine from my end. 
Here is the test case I have created:
https://codebrace.com/editor/afe98451c

Comment: I know the code is working, but...because firefox and chrome give a different value for the offset() that's why can't trigger the search bar on the same time in different browsers.

Comment: I have tested in both chrome and firefox. Your code worked as expected.

Comment: It's usually caused by cross browser differences. It's caused by the difference in positions and  element size in these browsers, so is the difference.

Comment: Usually Position at top differs and bottom remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
function getPosition(element) {
    console.log('getPosition');
    var xPos = (element.offsetLeft - element.scrollLeft + element.clientLeft);
    var yPos = (element.offsetTop - element.scrollTop + element.clientTop);

    return {
        x: xPos,
        y: yPos
    };
}
```

I removed the while loop, because i did not need the if statement, and the `el=el.offsetParent;` too because it changed the values. Now I'm getting the same values in every browser. Woohooo :)